# Voting Network Architecture

Tags: angularjs, laravel, networking, social-networking

Alright, My question could be a bit long, so kindly bear with me. 
I don't have any bug or some error but it's more about conceptual question.

I am building a social network website, much like 9gag.com  , So I have this up-votes and down-votes feature which will be associated with Posts, Comments and Replies made by the user.

I am building this website on Laravel and Angular and as my back-end and front-end frameworks respectively. And I have managed to built it as well.

Now everything is working great except I am sending 2 requests (HTTP) per comment and reply to ensure whether a user has already upvoted or downvoted that certain comment or reply. and in backend I do my querying to find whether he did or not and apply ng-classes accordingly but that just takes too much time and well obviously if there are 10 comments (limit) then it will make 20 requests, so my question is how to handle these whether logged In user has did this or not scenarios in the most elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the vote status in the API response that lists the comments.

Your API response should looks something like this for a logged-in user:

```
[{
    "id": 123,
    "text": "This is the comment. I voted it up.",
    "vote": "up"
},
{
    "id": 456,
    "text": "This is another comment. I haven't voted on it.",
    "vote": null
}
{
    "id": 789,
    "text": "This is another comment. I didn't like this one so I voted it down.",
    "vote": "down"
}]
```

Comment: Oh actually, I really liked the approach in the sense in my backend I will be ready with the response much like it will be iterating through every comment and reply associated to that post and tell whether the logged In user has upvoted it or downvoted it or not. and then I could make a GET/POST ajax request to fetch that data by sending the post ID.
Thank you so much, but I might wait for other people to come up with different approaches before marking your answer as approved. Cheers for helping out.